# What is the HashCode for inline Predicates?

Tags: java, lambda, hashcode, predicate

I'm using `Pattern.compile("XXX").asPredicate()` to create many predicates to process some data.  Looking at its implementation its only this

```
public Predicate<String> asPredicate() {
    return s -> matcher(s).find();
}
```

What is the hashcode for an inline generated predicate?  According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html it doesn't specify a hashcode... Comparing the values in my application it seems that its just a new hashcode every time, even for the same expression.  So I'm just curious as to how it gets its hash code in general.

Comment: why your are looking for hashcode? When you compare "String"s (mentioned in your example), you must use the "isEqual" method for comparing strings?

Comment: At this point just for knowledge.  I originally was wondering how I would cache the results of a filter if I was processing big lists with complex predicates.  I thought maybe a HashMap with a set of static predicates somewhere...  Either way not going down that road at the moment.

Comment: It simply uses the Object.hashCode() implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas will probably use `Object`’s default `hashCode()` implementation which returns something based on the object’s identity.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to override the implementation?  I'd like to know if two lambdas are the same.  (Have the same text)

Comment: Use the oldschool approach of creating an anonymous class, then.